# c# How to erase drawn lines in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, draw, lines

This WPF Application has 4 inputs where you can set the x, y values of two points and it draws a black line.  Problem is... i cant get rid of those lines after i draw them, so re-starting the app is ridiculous when i want to create new lines.
Here's what i have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Line objLine;
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tb1 = textBox.Text;
        string tb2 =  textBox1.Text;
        string tb3 = textBox3.Text;
        string tb4 = textBox4.Text;

        double tb1int = double.Parse(tb1);
        double tb2int = double.Parse(tb2);
        double tb3int = double.Parse(tb3);
        double tb4int = double.Parse(tb4);

        Line objLine = new Line(); //point input

        objLine.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        objLine.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

        objLine.X1 = tb1int;
        objLine.Y1 = tb2int;


        objLine.X2 = tb3int;
        objLine.Y2 = tb4int;

        hello.Children.Add(objLine);
}

 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (objLine != null)
        {
            hello.Children.Remove(objLine);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just remove it like `Children.Remove(line)`. Maybe your problem is that the Line object is local to the method, you can make it a global variable and hold a reference to it, this way you can remove the line whenever you want.

```
Line objLine;

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    objLine = new Line(); //point input
    ...
    hello.Children.Add(objLine);
}

private void removeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(objLine != null) {
       hello.Children.Remove(objLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have tried removing the `line` element from the `hello` container (first thing I'd do myself :)) and nothing happens.

what you might need to do is `invalidate` your UI. You need to redraw or refresh your UI in order to dynamically change content.

You could use [UIElement.InvalidateVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Or if it doesn't work, you might want to pass an `empty delegate` to refresh your UI. See [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx) on how to do it. 
Essentially, you would do something like this :

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

  public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
  {
    uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
  }
}
```

And then call `hello.Refresh()` on your container. Of course after removing the `line` element.

Comment: have no idea how to implement that lol, can u post code that one can copy/paste and it works?